# Anchor size increases on float

Tags: html, css, css-float

Image size is fixed to 42*42. But if we hover over anchor tag in inspect element, size is shown as 42*46. Why the size of anchor tag increases? Is it because I am using float?

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" 
style="float:left"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42"></a>
```

Comment: Does not change for me in Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `display` and `vertical-align` of `img`. Setting the `vertical-align` on the following works:

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" style="float:left">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" style="vertical-align: middle;" />
</a>
```